# How to create histogram of binary image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, histogram

I have binary image (only 2 color, black and white), [image: Binary Image]

I want to create histogram of the image. I have tried with these code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('bin_003.png')
color = ('b','g','r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.show()
```

But the code shows [image: Histogram]
instead of showing only 0 and 1 at the x axis.

Comment: White is (255,255,255) so I don't know why you're surprised.

Comment: Actually I'm not surprised, i mean, i want to make the axis become only "0" and "1". For example "0" for 0 and "1" for 255 @MarkRansom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a black and white image here, it should only have a single channel. You wouldn't need RGB channels. You may create a single histogram by using `plt.hist`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/y19dr.png')

plt.hist(img.flatten(), bins=[-.5,.5,1.5], ec="k")
plt.xticks((0,1))
plt.show()
```

[image]